# How to edit the custom option price type programmatically?

Tags: magento2, custom-options

I have a product which has 1 custom option (Size) with 3 custom options values (Standard,Medium,Large).

Now I am trying to change price type (price_type) 'fixed' to 'absolute'.
I fetched the option_type_id by using customOptions as below:

```
$customOptions = $obj->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option')->getProductOptionCollection($product);
foreach ($customOptions as $customOption) {
    $values = $customOption->getValues();
    foreach ($values as $value) {
    // fetched the option_type_id
    }
}
```

It stored in `catalog_product_option_type_price` table into the database.

Is there any way to update the price type directly from option_type_id?

How to do with ProductCustomOptionInterface?